# SharePoint Online New Team Site for groups

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites

When publishing news in a Group site it will showcase it under News (like this) what is the logic behind this??
[image]

In here it will publish only the news. Even if I create a page. It won't show there.

[image]

I need a code clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you download both pages and inspect the contents, you will find that in the news page , you have `PromotedState` value as **2**.

The contents in the news page are as below:

```
<mso:PromotedState msdt:dt="string">2.00000000000000</mso:PromotedState>
```

Where as in case of site page, its is as below:

```
<mso:PromotedState msdt:dt="string">0</mso:PromotedState>
```

Right now, you can only provision news page via the news list/news headlines webpart (not sure programmatically). If you create it via Site Contents > Site Pages, it will create a simple site page only which wont be visible inside news webpart since the `PromotedState` value is 0 in its case.

Reference - [What makes a page to be a news page on SharePoint Online](https://www.eliostruyf.com/what-makes-a-page-to-be-a-news-page-on-sharepoint-online/)

[Modern pages and news pages](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2016/11/modern-pages-and-news-pages.html)